# how to access files from drive.google.com using html?

Tags: css, html

I want to access an image inside drive.google.com using html img tag.How to write the URL to access the image

I tried using https://googledrive.com/host/file_code ,but no success

Comment: That link comes back as a error 404 not found....

Comment: http://cube3x.com/how-to-use-google-drive-as-cdn-for-your-website/

Comment: http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2013/04/how-to-host-css-or-javascript-files-in-blogger-using-google-drive.html

Comment: It's the URL that is confusing me,i have tried it,but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Google Drive is not designed for hosting arbitrary files.

If you want a third party hosting service, use something like Amazon S3